# Redux, Do I have to import store in all my containers if I want to have access to the data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Perhaps I am not wrapping my head around redux, but all the examples I've seen don't really access state too much between containers and so I haven't seen much usage of store.getState(), but even if you want to dispatch, you need access to store, right?

So, other than importing
import store from 'path/to/store/store'

in every file that I want to getState() or "dispatch", how do I get access to that state because if I don't include it, store is undefined.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In general you want to only make top-level container components ones that have access to the store - they will pass down any necessary data or action dispatches as props to their children components. This is the difference between a "smart" and a "dumb" component - "smart" components know about the Redux store/state, while "dumb" components just get props passed to them and have no idea about the bigger application state.

However, even just passing the store to container components can become tedious. That's why React-Redux provides one component out of the box that wraps your entire application. [Check it out](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider) in the docs. This is the `Provider` component and when you wrap your whole app with it, you only pass the store to a component *once*:

```js
import createStore from '../store';

const store = createStore()

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainAppContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see here, I have a separate configuration file just for my store as there is a lot of modification you can do and for any remotely complex app, you'll find yourself doing the same for things like using [compose](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) to apply middleware.

Then any of your remaining "smart" components (generally wrappers) need to listen to the store. This is accomplished using the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) method. This allows you to map pieces of the state to your component properties as well as dispatch actions as properties.

```js
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = function(state){
  return {
    something: state.something,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    getSomething: actionCreators.getSomething,
  }, dispatch)
}

class MainAppContainer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      //now has access to data like this.props.something, which is from store
      //now has access to dispatch actions like this.props.getSomething
    }

    render() {
        //will pass down store data and dispatch actions to child components
        return (
               <div>
                   <ChildComponent1 something={this.props.something} />
                   <ChildComponent2 getSomething={this.props.getSomething} />
               </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainAppContainer)
```

Because you are always passing down dispatch actions and data to your children component as properties, you just reference those on that component with `this.props`.

Building off the example above, you'll see that because I passed `this.props.something` to `ChildComponent1`, it has access to the `something` data from the store but it does not have access to the `getSomething` dispatch action. Likewise, `ChildComponent2` only has access to the `getSomething` dispatch action but not the `something` data. This means that you only expose components to exactly what they need from the store.

For example, because `ChildComponent2` was passed down the dispatch action as `getSomething`, in my `onClick` I can call `this.props.getSomething` and it will call the dispatch action *without needing any access to the store*. In the same way it can continue to pass down `getSomething` to another child component and that component could call it and/or pass it down and the cycle could continue indefinitely.

```js
class ChildComponent2 extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.props.getSomething}>Click me</div>
                <NestedComponent getSomething={this.props.getSomething} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Edit from the comments**

While this doesn't pertain directly to the question, in the comments you seemed a little confused about actions. I did not actually define the action `getSomething` here. Instead it is usual in Redux apps to put all of your action definitions in a separate file called `actionCreators.js`. This contains functions that are named the same as your actions and return an object with a `type` property and any other methods/data that action requires. For instance, here's a very simple example `actionCreators.js` file:

```js
export function getSomething() {
    return {
        type: 'GET_SOMETHING',
        payload: {
            something: 'Here is some data'
        }
    }
}
```

This action type is what your reducer would listen for to know which action was being fired.

Comment: thank you!! Now, what if you have a child component uner MainAppContainer, lets say, "childAppContainer", can you show an example how that would then deal with state & dispatcing an action?
So, if you wanted to "update" state in ChildComponent2, you'd say something like "getSomething.AddSomething.dispatch(SOME_CONST_ACTION_NAME);

Comment: bro,  you are gonna kill me! lol.. You have helped tremendously, thank you! But I am slightly (and I have read the docs), askew in understanding how the function "this.props.getSomething", gets an actionType - wouldn't you pass it in? I'm assuming you aren't using dispatch beause we bound it. Thanks again, and if this is too much lol, I totally understand. no worries.

Comment: No worries, man. I did not set an action type on `getSomething` or even define it because usually people define all actions for their app in a separate file called `actionCreators.js`. This would be a file just filled with functions that return an object with a `type` property and anything else needed for the action. So on that component I would actually need to import the 'getSomething` function from `actionCreators.js` as well as the `bindActionCreators` module from `redux`. I left out those import statements to clean up the code a little but I can add them back in.

Comment: Okay I added those import statements and a bit at the bottom explaining the actions in more depth. Hope that helps.

Comment: getSomething() must not call getState()  ? when it's needed to get store's values

Comment: It should be noted, at least now, that a single top level connected component isn't the hard recommended approach for every case. As your app scales, you might want to connect other components to avoid prop hell. https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/668585589609005056

Comment: The link https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store you reference returns HTTP status 404.

Comment: Wow!! nicely explained. @AndyNoelker hats off 

Answer (score 15):

If you use the `react-redux` package, you'll end up wrapping your components in a `Provider` with a `store` prop. This sets up your single store in a React context, which is then accessed from the `connect` method in child components. The `connect` method takes two functions (mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps), which are your hooks for getting state from the store and dispatching messages.

[Take a look here for more information](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-with-provider-from-react-redux)

Comment: So if you have 10 container components, each container component will need to have its own connect() implementation, mapStateToProps() and mapDispatchToProps()?  How is this saving any typing and time?  I thought each container component could just access the store directly. The prototypical use case would be a User object that needs to be accessible anywhere to almost every child and grandchild component.  How would children easily access the User object inside the store?

Comment: @user798719 you can still access to store, and not use mapStateToProps() and mapDispatchToProps(), but you will be tightly coupling your components to redux.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi - I think it's better to have each component directly talk with the state (redux) than having to endlessly pass props from component to children component, who knows how deep...that is such an ugly thing to be doing.

Comment: @user798719 you can create a HOC and wrap any components that need to be connected to store. example: export default connectorWrapper(MyComponent), connectorWrapper is HOC that contains mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps and return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(WrappedComponent), if need some codes, inform me please, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

with mapStateToProps
**React Component:**

```
import Item from './Item.jsx';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { getProduct, addProduct } from '../../actions';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Bundles extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    var productData = this.props.productData
    return (
      <div>
        <span>
          {
            productData.map(item => (
              <Item item={item} key={item.id} />
            ))
          }

        </span>
      </div >
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // console.log(state.getProduct)
  return {
    productData: state.getProduct,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Bundles);
```

**Product Reducers**

```
const productReducer = (state = data, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_PRODUCT":
      console.log(state)
      return state
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default productReducer;
```

**RootReducer (all reducers combined)**

```
import getProduct from './products';
import getReviews from './reviews';

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  cartReducer, getProduct, getReviews
})

export default allReducers;
```

**Action (action/index.js)**

```
      // console.log('hahahahah')
      return {
        type: 'ADD_PRODUCT',
        payload: n
      }
    }
```