# Issue accessing store and calling actionCreators

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm in the process of learning React Native with Redux and can't wrap my head around how to access the store/actionCreators from within my components.  I feel like I've tried ten or so variants of code, watched most of Dan Abramov's Egghead videos (multiple times), and still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I think the best explanation I've seen so far is the accepted answer here: [Redux, Do I have to import store in all my containers if I want to have access to the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300419/redux-do-i-have-to-import-store-in-all-my-containers-if-i-want-to-have-access-t)

The error I get is:  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.clinic.drName').  Here are the relevant bits of code:

I'm passing the store via the Provider (so I think):

```
index.ios.js
import clinicReducer from './reducers/clinic';

import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    clinic : clinicReducer
});

let store = createStore(combineReducers({clinicReducer}));

//testing - log every action out
let unsubscribe = store.subscribe( () =>
    console.log(store.getState())
);

class ReactShoeApp extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ReactNative.NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                  title: 'React Shoe App',
                  component: Index
            }}/>
        </Provider>
    );
}
}
```

Here is my actionCreator:

```
export const CLINIC_DR_NAME_UPDATE = 'CLINIC_DR_NAME_UPDATE_UPDATE';

export function updateClinicDrName(newValue) {
    return {type: CLINIC_DR_NAME_UPDATE, value: newValue};
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```
import {
    CLINIC_DR_NAME_UPDATE
} from '../actions/';

let cloneObject = function(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
};

const initialState = {
    drName : null
};

export default function clinicReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CLINIC_DR_NAME_UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                drName: action.value
            };
            default:
                return state || newState;
       }
    }
```

and here is my component:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = function(state){
    return {
        drName: state.clinic.drName,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        updateClinicDrName: Actions.updateClinicDrName,
    }, dispatch)
};


//class definition
class Clinic extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <TextGroup label={'Dr. Name'} placeholder={'placeholder'} value={this.props.drName} onChangeText={(text) => this.handlers.onNameChange({text})}></TextGroup>
                <TextGroup label={'City'} placeholder={'placeholder'}></TextGroup>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Clinic);
```

All I'm trying to do is update the store (clinic.drName) when the user types in the Dr Name Text Group.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're mismatching the way you call `combineReducers()` with the name of the slice you're expecting.  This is a common mistake.  You're defining an object with the key `clinicReducer`, but expecting the data to be at a key named `clinic`.

See [Defining State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html#defining-state-shape)  for an explanation of the problem.

Also, your `clinicReducer()` function looks odd, and has several issues:

- Don't access variables outside the function like you are with `newState`.
- Don't do deep-cloning like that (per [Redux FAQ: Performance](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-clone-state)).  Instead, use "shallow cloning" to update the state if necessary (see examples at [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html)).
- It looks like the reducer is double-nesting the data it's trying to access as well.

I *think* you want something more like:

```
// clinicReducer.js

const initialState = {
    drName : null
};

export default function clinicReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CLINIC_DR_NAME_UPDATE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                drName : actino.value
            };
        }
        default: return state        
    }
}


// index.js

import clinicReducer from "./reducers/clinic";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    clinic : clinicReducer
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I modified my question so that it contains the correct code and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? I see two issues with what you have.

1. `newState.clinic.drName = action.value;` should be throwing a typeError. So for this to work you need to change newState to:

   `const newState = {
     clinic: {}
   }`
2. What is `this.handlers.onNameChange({text})`? I think you need to change this to `this.props.updateClinicDrName(text)`.