# Initial Load of Data for Different React Container Components - Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using react-redux.

When you have various pages on your site such as list of companies, list of jobs, etc. and lets say you have top level containers for those such as `<CompanyList />` and `<JobList />`, in your component where do you make that dispatch call? Usually in containers you only call dispatch for handlers.

Reducers specify initial state.  But what if I have several types of pages and entities in my app?  Trying to figure out how just rendering a read only list is orchestrated amongst different type of Container components in an app.

When you first create the store you have the option to specify initial state there, but I'm just saying do it in the reducer.  So lets say for `<CompanyList />` how does it know where to grab initial state..in my mapDispatchToProps is that where I'd call dispatch or something with say an action such as "GET_ALL" for companies?

Comment: *"But what if I have several types of pages and entities in my app?"* Why do think initial state in reducers would be different with multiple components?

Comment: because I don't need the whole state tree for sub components.  I need specific filtered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you have various pages on your site such as list of companies, list of jobs, etc. and let's say you have top level containers for those such as and, in your component where do you make that dispatch call? Usually, in containers, you only call dispatch for handlers.

You can do it in the containers, but I prefer triggering actions directly. If I have to trigger an action after another one I would use the [react-thunk middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) and make use of promises as I explained [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981460/react-native-redux-action-dispatched-return-results/41982581#41982581).

Let's consider we have our actions creators in an `action.js` file as shown below:

*action.js*

```
/*
 * action types
 */
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
export const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
export const SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER'


/*
 * other constants
 */

export const VisibilityFilters = {
  SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
  SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
  SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
}

/*
 * action creators
 */

export function addTodo(text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}

export function toggleTodo(index) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
}

export function setVisibilityFilter(filter) {
  return { type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, filter }
}
```

The actions will be used in a container `TodoList` as:

*TodoList.js*

```
import react, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { addTodo, ToggleTodo, setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions/actions'
//import * as actions from '../actions/actions' this is a shorter way when you want to use all the actions in the actions file in the component.

class ToDoList extends Component {
   render () {
     //Rendering logic here
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { todos, counter } = state
    return { todos, counter }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  // here is how I would map the actions individually
  return {
    addTodo: bindActionCreators(addTodo, dispatch),
    ToggleTodo: bindActionCreators(ToggleTodo, dispatch),
    setVisibilityFilter: bindActionCreators(setVisibilityFilter, dispatch)
  }


  //Or if you want to map all the actions in a single shot.
  //return {
  //  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) 
  //}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList)
```

Like that the actions will be available to the `TodoList` Component as props. You will call the directly like:

```
this.props.addTodo(todo); //if the actions were imported mapped individually.

//Or
this.props.actions.addTodo(todo); //if all the actions were imported and mapped using `actions`.
```

> When you first create the store you have the option to specify initial state there, but I'm just saying do it in the reducer. So lets say for  how does it know where to grab initial state..in my mapDispatchToProps is that where I'd call dispatch or something with say an action such as "GET_ALL" for companies?

I think the [redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) explains this so well. When using the redux pattern one will usually create a reducer for each `root` attribute of the initial state, and create a reducer for it. It is the job of the `combineReducer` to bind the reducer to each `root` attribute of the initial state. You will notice for the redux document that they used:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import counter from './counter'

export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  counter
})
```

One will noticed the initial state of the store is having the element with keys
`todos` and `counter`. Say you instead wrote the reducers for the initial state as `todosReducers` and `counterReducer` then you shall map them to the store as:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todosReducer from './todosReducer'
import counterReducer from './counterReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  todos: todosReducer,
  counter: counterReducer
})
```

Doing all that, redux will always pass the fraction of the state of the store to your reducers. So the `state` that is passed to the reducer like:

```
function counter(state = 0, action)
```

is actually the `store.state.counter`, and the reducer is expected to return a new state for this "state". So in the reducers, you will not have the whole state of the store to handle.

Also, see [normalizing state shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) from the redux documentation. This helps when your application has a complex state in your store. When the state is normalized it becomes easier to reduce.

Comment: thanks this explained it a lot better than the docs.  I'm sorry but the docs and that todo app is a horrible example from Dan.  Thanks.

Comment: also I was chatting in the Discord community for Redux.  One guy says to just use an anonymous function for mapStateToProps:  connect(
  state => { records: selectRecords(state) },
  { fetchRecords },
)

Comment: also in case this helps anyone another good post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300419/redux-do-i-have-to-import-store-in-all-my-containers-if-i-want-to-have-access-t

Comment: "I prefer triggering actions directly" - calling them from where?  what do you mean, where and how are you calling the action?

Comment: I just added that to my answer @PositiveGuy.