# Redux Shared Module for Parent and Child Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm using [React-Redux-Starter-Kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) and am confused on how to bring in nested components that share the same reducer/store (e.g.: module). In this case, the nested component needs to be using the same module as the parent (I realize that references and functions can be passed down, but I want to access the module directly).

I will use a very trivial example to ask my question: `<Foo />` component is wired up to have a route `/foo/:fooId` and in its view `<Bar />` component is present (this doesn't have a route).

Here's an overview of the structure (I haven't figured out how to nest Bar inside of Foo yet... that will be another question)

```
routes
├── Foo
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Foo.js
│   ├── containers
│   │   └── FooContainer.js
│   ├── modules
│   │   └── foo.js
│   └── index.js
├── Bar
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Bar.js
│   ├── containers
│   │   └── BarContainer.js
│   └── index.js
└── index.js
```

Here's Bar's index.js:

```
import { injectReducer } from '../../store/reducers';

export default (store) => ({
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const Bar = require('./containers/BarContainer').default
      const reducer = require('../Foo/modules/foo').default
      injectReducer(store, { key: 'foo', reducer })
      cb(null, Bar)
    }, 'bar')
  }
});
```

Here's Bar's container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { someCoolFunctionOnFooModule } from '../../Foo/modules/foo'
import Bar from '../components/Bar'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someCoolFunctionOnFooModule
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  someItemThatBarNeeds: state.foo.someItemThatBarNeeds
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Bar)
```

Here's Bar's component:

```
import React from 'react'

class Bar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.someCoolFunctionOnFooModule()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.someItemThatBarNeeds}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Bar
```

...when I `import Bar from '../../Bar/components/Bar'` or `import Bar from '../../Bar'` and put `<Bar />` in Foo's view, it doesn't work. Moreover, my `console.debug('here')` in Bar's index.js isn't showing up. This leads me to think that the component and container aren't getting wired up correctly with Redux.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code where you're importing `Bar/index.js` ? Maybe the code where you're importing `Foo/index.js` as well

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I'm putting `import Bar from '../../Bar/components/Bar'` and `import Bar from '../../Bar'` in `Foo/components/Foo.js` - Not importing both at the same time, obviously. Testing with both in isolation

Comment: Should I be registering Bar as a child route of Foo with redux-router? Sorry if this is a silly question

Comment: Bar's index file is a function that adds Bar specific reducer to your redux store. so at the very least you need to call that function somewhere passing your redux store. that's unrelated to your bar container though, which also needs to be imported if you want to render it anywhere like foo.

Comment: > bar container needs to be imported if you want to render it anywhere like foo

Not sure I follow you here

Comment: BarContainer imports Bar the component and returns a component that is connected to your redux store. If you want to render Bar inside Foo, you would import BarContainer in Foo and put it somewhere in Foo's render function. This is separate to setting up your Bar reducer though. Why did you choose this starter kit? I think you might need to the hello world examples from the redux docs first

Comment: Hi again. I did read the Redux docs/overview Starter Kit extensively before posting the question. I think I see what you're getting at with "you would import BarContainer in Foo and put it somewhere in Foo's render function"... what I did was import BarComponent in Foo and put it somewhere in Foo's render function. I didn't realize one had to import the container to use the component.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for me to somehow get the component from importing the Bar/index.js because that "binds" the container/component/reducer ?

Comment: The export of `index.js` is not a component though. It's a function that takes `store` and returns an object with a `getComponent` method. This is way outside of the React api.

Comment: Okay, I completely get it now. This was really the solution I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300419/redux-do-i-have-to-import-store-in-all-my-containers-if-i-want-to-have-access-t - my whole "I realize that references and functions can be passed down, but I want to access the module directly" was a misnomer all along - do you know of a way to mark a question as duplicate?